# Custom Template not rendering

Tags: php, silverstripe

This is my `NgFieldGroup.ss` (straight copy of `FieldGroup.ss` plus `$AttributesHTML`

```
<div $AttributesHTML class="<% if $extraClass %>$extraClass<% else %>fieldgroup<% end_if %><% if $Zebra %> fieldgroup-zebra<% end_if %>" <% if $ID %>id="$ID"<% end_if %>>
    <test-bad-html>
    <% loop $FieldList %>
        <div class="fieldgroup-field $FirstLast $EvenOdd">
            $SmallFieldHolder
        </div>
    <% end_loop %>
    </test-bad-html>
</div>
```

The template is assigned by the following inside a form

```
FieldGroup::create(null,[ /*...*/ ])->setAttribute("ng-show","action")->setTemplate("NgFieldGroup")
```

As you can see in this image, the Debugger shows that `$this->getTemplate()` clearly has `NgFieldGroup` assigned to it, yet in the base `renderWith` method it is nowhere to be seen.

[image: Debugger Info]

---

What is going on here?

Comment: Did you do `dev/build?flush=1` beforehand?

Comment: @bummzack yes, multiple times

Comment: I even find myself deleting the silverstripe-cache folder entirely sometimes to ensure this is rebuilt

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `NgFieldGroup.ss`is a template for a field **holder** - not for a field? You can set a FieldHolder with `$field->setFieldHolderTemplate("NgFieldGroup");`

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort you can always specify a template there and then... with `fromString`...

```
FieldGroup::create(null,[ /*...*/ ])
    ->setAttribute("ng-show","action")
    ->setTemplate(SSViewer::fromString('
        <div $AttributesHTML class="<% if $extraClass %>$extraClass<% else %>fieldgroup<% end_if %><% if $Zebra %> fieldgroup-zebra<% end_if %>" <% if $ID %>id="$ID"<% end_if %>>
            <test-bad-html>
            <% loop $FieldList %>
            <div class="fieldgroup-field $FirstLast $EvenOdd">
                $SmallFieldHolder
            </div>
            <% end_loop %>
            </test-bad-html>
        </div>
    '));
```

Not pretty but removes all confusion about where the template comes from.